# Can sbt-idea generate project files based on existing ones?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, sbt-idea

I have been using `sbt` and `sbt-idea` for a while and for the most part it works perfectly - unfortunately there is one key use case where it doesn't.

The use case is when you are working on a project based on the output of gen-idea.  Everything works perfect (as expected).  Then you change the project setting to enable `fsc` (Fast Scala Compiler) in the project settings - still good.

You need `slf4s` as a dependency so you add it to the project's `build.sbt`.  It is not picked up by Intellij yet (expected), so you go back to your sbt console, `reload`, `gen-idea`.  This causes Intellij to alert you to reload the project.  You do as it recommends and now s`lf4s` is recognized by Intellij.  Great, but now the project no longer has `fsc` enabled because `gen-idea` re-wrote your project files.

For this instance its easy enough to re-enable fsc, but in general this doesn't scale if I need to re-configure my project every time I run gen-idea.

Is there a way to tell `sbt-idea` to modify the current project files instead of creating new ones each time or base the new ones on the old ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is not about modifying the project, which the question asks, but about FSC support.

Enabling FSC by default should work in the current trunk version based on [this](https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea/issues/99) issue from Nov 2011.

But it seems that the current published version `0.11.0` is too old to include this patch.

Comment: This is now part of the latest build. `addSbtPlugin("com.github.mpeltonen" % "sbt-idea" % "1.0.0")` works for me.